# strtotime не работает с точками

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой при использовании strtotime(). Функция неправильно взаимодействует с точками

```
$date = "21.08.19";
echo date("d-m-y", strtotime($date));
```

Вернет 23-05-19.

Вариант с DateTime::createFromFormat не подходит, так как в $date может прилетать несколько разных форматов и работа функции strtotime меня в целом устраивает.

Есть какое-то простое решение данной проблемы?

Comment: В соответствии с описанием функция *strtotime — Преобразует текстовое представление даты на английском языке в метку времени Unix*. А у "даты на английском языке" нет понимания, что точка может являться разделителем.

Comment: Почитайте про работу `strtotime()` и форматы.. Тут у вас 2 варианта имеется: либо заменять `.` на `-` => `str_replace('.','-',$date);` либо год писать полностью, тогда ничего заменять не надо..

Comment: на самом деле я думаю что распознавание точки зависит от локали.

Comment: @Akina если разделителем является точка то это указывает только на использование формата `d-m-y`, тут "дата на английском" подразумевает буквально дату на английском, аля "next Tuesday" или "23 May 2019"

Comment: @Ипатьев не зависит от локали ничего, зависит от самой строки даты - от формата и от разделителя

Comment: @InDevX я всегда полагал, что формат и разделитель зависят от локали